# WCF service with protocol buffer, how the config file will look like

Tags: c#, protocols, protocol-buffers, app-config, servicecontract

I worked on WCF before. But I am very new in protocol buffers. I went through its advantages and how to use it. Basically i want to plug in the protocol buffers into my existing 'WCF library'. So what changes should i make in my existing 'app.config' file to introduce or start working with protocol buffers? 
My existing service Config file is as follows.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="XYZProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="XYZshipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.XYZProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf35678563123ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856564ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="wcfServiceXYZApplication.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/XYZApplication/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="XYZApplication.IService1" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000" maxBufferSize="100000" maxBufferPoolSize="100000"/>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the modifications i did in config for the service side

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="XYZProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="XYZshipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.XYZProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf35678563123ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856564ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="protoEndpointBehavior">
      <protobuf/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="namedPipeBinding" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="0:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="WcfProtobufService.SimpleService">
    <endpoint binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="namedPipeBinding" contract="WcfProtobufService.ISimpleService" behaviorConfiguration="protoEndpointBehavior"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/console/SimpleService.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="protobuf" type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

along with this i changed client side config file too...Just change system.serviceModel section as follows

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="protoEndpointBehavior">
          <protobuf/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_ISimpleService" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="0:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/console/SimpleService.svc"
          binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_ISimpleService"
          contract="SimpleProxy.ISimpleService" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_ISimpleService" behaviorConfiguration="protoEndpointBehavior">
      </endpoint>
    </client>

    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="protobuf" type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Also To enable protobuf serialization for your WCF Data Contracts, first you need to

1. add the [ProtoContract] attribute to every DTO (Data Transfer
   Object)    that needs the [DataContract] attribute and the
   [ServiceContract]    attribute..
2. add the [ProtoMember] attribute to every DTO data field that needs
   the [DataMember] attribute.

   changes for IService

   ```
       [ProtoMember(2)]
       [DataMember(Order = 0)]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   ```

   changes for service- just add Protocontract attribute over the service contract

   [ProtoContract]
   [ServiceContract]

Last but not least add

```
using ProtoBuf
```

Refered ...

https://whinery.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/wcf-with-protobuf-serialization/

Comment: Please put enough information in your answer so that even if the link dies, your answer is still useful. Currently this is a link-only answer which is a candidate for deletion.

Comment: Thanks for informing me ... I will share actual solution which i implemented .

Comment: That's much better. Thanks for taking the time to put the info into the answer.

Comment: Thanks... I am not sure how to deal with 'ban on asking questions' ? not able to ask any question from this account. i edited all of the questions with more explaination, deleted duplicate questions.. still same problem. can you suggest me something?

Comment: As an addition to above solution, if you don't want to configure via App/Web.config files on both client and server side, then add `using ProtoBuf.ServiceModel;` and to your service interface functions add `[ProtoBehavior]`